# Slide Over and Split View is not enabling

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uikit

I am trying to enable Slide Over and Split View in the iPad application.But in the side menu my application is missing.

I am using this guide that is presented in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015145-CH13-SW1).

I do this steps:

- Set the Base SDK to “Latest iOS,” as described in Setting the Base
  SDK in App Distribution Guide.
- Provide a LaunchScreen.storyboard file (instead of a .png image file
  as you did in iOS 7 and earlier), as described in Creating a Launch
  Screen File in App Distribution Guide.
- In your project’s Info.plist file, in the “Supported interface
  orientations (iPad)” array.

In the project.

LaunchScreen.storyboard

[image]

Base SDK

[image]

iPad Orientation

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you tried unchecking `Requires full screen`? In iPad it prevent `Multi Window` support.

Answer (score 5):

That tutorial says:

> The required `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file for your app must employ Auto Layout.

Have you set `LaunchScreen.storyboard` to your project settings?

[image]

I have do these in project settings:

1. Uncheck `Requires full screen`.
2. Set 4 orientations for iPad.
3. et `LaunchScreen.storyboard` to Launch Screen file.

than works.